# What are basic programs like, recursion, Fibonacci, small trick programs?

Tags: programming-languages, recursion, coding-style

This question may seem daft (I'm a new to 'programming' and should probably stop if this is the type of question I'm required to ask)...

What are:

> "basic programs like, recursion, fibonacci, factorial, string manipulation, small trick programs"?

I've recently read  [Coding Horror - the non programmer](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/02/the-nonprogramming-programmer.html) and followed the links to [Kegel and How to get hired](http://www.kegel.com/academy/getting-hired.html).

Then I  delved through some similar questions here (hence the block quote) and I realised that as a fully fledged non-programmer I probably wouldn't know if I knew recursion (or any of the others) because I wouldn't know what it looked like, or why it was used, and what the results would look like after it was used.

I suppose I'm trying to get a picture of "the basics". What the principles are and why we learn them - where they'll be used and what result/s your looking for.

If they'll be used as an interview question during my first interview sometime in 2020 I would like to look less ignorant than those 199 out of 200 who just don't know the how, or the why, of programming.

As always...I'll get my coat.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: if you are truly interested in programming you will have learned all these, in a natural way, by the year 2020 :) You do not have to specifically search for them .. The everyday life of programming will lead you to all these concepts on its own .

Comment: I admire your honesty Mike. 

It's always difficult to take on new learning and programming certainly isn't the easiest thing in the world to pick up.  I will admit this much, some of the more 'academic' programming problems that colleges and universities teach you how to solve are rarely used in the commercial world at all. That being said, the knowledge of 'how' to solve these more academic problems can be helpful. Gaby was right, as you go, you'll pick them up anyway. 

Best of luck Mike. Welcome to the programming world :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can get into concepts like recursion, you need to learn the basics, as you said.  I'm not sure what your education level is or where you're planning to go with it, but my favorite programming text is "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist" ([link text](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/)).

This will teach you the core fundamentals of programming, and you need to understand these building blocks before you delve deeper.

Comment: Nice link. At the moment I'm just reading books and carrying out exercises. Goal: I'm planning to build little programs (applications) and solve small puzzles, but I need to learn a lot more until I can build anything.

Comment: That's exactly how to do it!  Programming is all about solving the little puzzles first, and then putting those solutions together to solve a bigger puzzle.
When you're ready for it, projecteuler.net has a lot of fun (but challenging) puzzles to solve.  Good luck on your education and happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

**Traveling Salesman Problem**

Comment: Does that means it's an unanswerable question? Sort of like how long is a piece of string...